# I setup an asterisk Server, but now i can't access to web admin area

Tags: mysql, asterisk

I setup an asterisk server on CentOS 6.x 64bit
It's all ok, but after one week when i come back, i can't access to web admin area.

This is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)::SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)  

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)::SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)::SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)::SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)::SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)::SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: try a manuell connect to the DB use : mysql -S /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock -u USERNAME -p and see if you can login. if not post the error message

Comment: Thank you!! 
ok, i see there is a problem with mysql! the error message is: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: yes - the db server is not running. if you cant start post the error from server

Comment: [root@Asterisk ~]# mysql -S /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
[root@Asterisk ~]# 


Thanks!

Comment: this wars the error message from the client. this means there is no socket from DB. So now i must know why the Database not start.  try: /etc/init.d/mysql start - to start the server and whe it ok then to connect again

Comment: Thanks for your help.

This is the output: -bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory

uhmm

Comment: is the db installed on the same server ? try (only for test) # mysqld  and see the output. there you can see why the db not started

Comment: or try # mysql.server start

Comment: Output: -bash: mysql.server: command not found

I dint uninstall the mysql........ uhm

Comment: we test it. is there a db config file: try # cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf  , if there is one try : find / -name mysql -print  to find any location where a mysql file is

Answer (score 0):

[root@Asterisk ~]# sudo yum install mysql-server
Plugin abilitati:fastestmirror, presto, priorities, security
Impostazione processo di installazione
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: it.centos.contactlab.it
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: it.centos.contactlab.it
 * rpmforge: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * updates: it.centos.contactlab.it
Il pacchetto mysql-server-5.1.73-5.el6_7.1.x86_64 è già installato e aggiornato all'ultima versione
Niente da fare
[root@Asterisk ~]# sudo /sbin/service mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
[root@Asterisk ~]#

Comment: try (only for test) # mysqld     --- not mysql and see output

Comment: do you have teamviewer ? so i can see the shell

Comment: find / -name mysqld -print    - if found like /usr/xxxx/xxx/mysqld start this with the hole path

Comment: [root@Asterisk ~]# find / -name mysqld -print 
/var/run/mysqld
/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld
/etc/logrotate.d/mysqld
/usr/libexec/mysqld
[root@Asterisk ~]#

Comment: try # /usr/libexec/mysqld

Comment: I respose with new answer

Comment: it looks bad. if you not found we can chat tomorrow. i now must go to work

Comment: Hello! Any news for me?

Answer (score 0):

/usr/libexec/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
160512 23:40:37 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160512 23:40:37  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
160512 23:40:37  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: auto-extending data file ./ibdata1 is of a different size
InnoDB: 0 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file:
InnoDB: initial 640 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
160512 23:40:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160512 23:40:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160512 23:40:37 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Error writing file '/var/lib/mysql/Asterisk.pid' (Errcode: 28)
160512 23:40:37 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No space left on device